# shatter an object?

Tags: physics

I made fractures in an object, I thought it would shatter by the liquid in side the object (the liquid is moving wildly) but it didn't. I tried to make a projectile that would collide with the object to shatter it, but it goes through the object (I checked both objects whether they have collision properties).

How do I let an object (which already has fractures) actually shatter apart by collision?

Comment: The collision system and the fluid sim system are using different math and are separate isolated systems as far as I know. Maybe someone else can elaborate more. It's physics, but it's still faked physics, in order to be manageable by your computer's processor. I think you'll need to explode that fractured object first, bake that, then splash the liquid against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to get the desired result.

Using the [Explode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcI9vFfdGpo) modifier.
Using the [Cell Fracture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ) add-on.

Both options have a number of settings that can be defined & tweaked.

Edit:
Sorry I misread a little bit. Depending on how your fractures were made [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY7iJmqsJf8) of the Cell Fracture tutorial should help. Otherwise you may need to explode your mesh.

Comment: thanks! that tutorial helped me. Ironically he's making exact the same thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Happy blending!